# Data layer design creation

Tags: c#

I am planning to create a public facing website somethings on the lines of each user having a single profile page which they can maintain/update regularly. On this page the user can upload some pics and update their personal information.
I have 3 tier structure in mind.

I need inputs in creating my data layer. I have read many posts but I am not convinced on which particular approach to finalize. I have read about entity framework, Microsoft enterprise library, core ado.net etc. Many blogs say that its best to use plain ado.net for better performance.

Could you point out which could be the best approach for my case where I am looking for faster processing and performance. In terms of technology I am looking for asp.net, c#, data calls with WCF and No MVC.

Also in case of plain ado.net are there any ready to use Library available which I could use and get started with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not go with plane ADO.NET, if you're looking at whole picture, I would consider that as an micro optimization - by using caching, smart data structuring you would achieve much more than by using plain ado.net.
Entity Framework adds some cost, there's no doubt about it, it is shown here (although it may be outdated):

http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/

You could use some micro orm framework, that is mentioned in benchmark, but usually micro comes at is own cost, for example most of micro frameworks I've seen have problems with joins (they allow them in pure sql, but have no tools for writing in typed c#).
For example Stackoverflow has people profiles and is using micro ORM Dapper and their performance is great, because if I remember correctly ~95% of requests are served from Reddis cache, not database.

If your public profiles will be full text searchable and you'll have millions of them, may be relational database is not the right choice.

Comment: I looked into dapper.net and it looks good. So currently I have structure like Presentation Layer, Business Layer, Data Layer. So with dapper.net all my Db class objects would be in Business layer? The class provided by dapper would be in data layer? I also want to use WCF api in making db calls. Could you please tell me how would I make calls from UI to business to data layer using this.

Comment: Haven't used Dapper, but in general data entity classes belong to data layer, then business layer and presentation layer may have own DTOs to transfer data between layers. Regarding WCF - unless there's specific need for SOAP, I would avoid it nowadays, there's WebApi and ServiceStack - they are more lightweight versions of WCF in my opinion, also in mobile world they are more convenient. Overall, I would suggest think simpler, otherwise your scope is growing too fast, may be read some of Ayende's posts, he hates complex things: http://ayende.com/blog/19457